# Images not loading from storage.googleapis.com

Tags: 18.04

Actually google images are not loading in my browser. Neither in Firefox nor in Chrome. I think it's a system problem.

For example, this link could not be loaded in my browser: 
https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-datasets-images/59981/116390/33f700110d8d2e206c59265084efea42/dataset-cover.jpg?t=2018-10-06-10-03-38

Console output in development tools in case of link clicking:

```
ssl-connection-error
```

Can someone guide me for troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: This is an image which goes straight to Downloads. Do you have nothing there?

Comment: No nothing happened. In firefox gives: Secure Connection Failed

Comment: Press Shift + Ctrl + I and check the Console for error messages about the connection.

Comment: its: _ssl-connection-error_

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling of `openssl` and `ca-certificates` packages could solve the issue:

```
sudo apt update && sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates openssl && sudo apt install ca-certificates openssl
```

You could check if your openssl package version is correct. The [Default](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/openssl) vs installed:

```
openssl version
```

You could also check if it works for a different user session.

Try also:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Answer `ask` to see what it offers for you.

Comment: Thank you @Gryu for your suggestions. After reinstalling openssl and ca-certificates, if I run _openssl version_, it gives output like this: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018. Can you tell me what should I do now?

Comment: Try reboot and check if issue appears again.

Comment: Tried but nothing happened!

Comment: Try also to create new user, login with it and try to load that image again using chrome or firefox from different user session.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I just noticed another phenomenon. When I activated VPN, everything works properly. Otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: You could try purge your vpn server and reinstall certificates and check. Then try install vpn again.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give update.

Comment: I tried according to all your suggestions but still no improvements.